# Is there a any way to update my app when its running?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I made an app which coded by Tkinter/Python. I need to update when i need to and my server and other things are ready to work. But i can't figure out how can i update my app when it's running.

Based on **Windows**.

I created a second app and running it at the beginning to check updates and after that, It runs main application. But in this way, i can't let user to click any button to check updates in main application run. Because windows doesn't let to change things in current running app.

What can i do for check my updates in single main application? *(Using Python/Tkinter/PyInstaller)*

Comment: you can check for updates from main app and if update needs run your updater application with subprocess.popen and exit from main. when you updated run main application again from updater in the same way.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, I need second app which for update. Any other way to do it only in single app?

Comment: you can't touch the file of an application if it's running. it's locked by system. you can create a daemon process and close main application but isn't so easy.